# Version of Chevalley's Theorem proving $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a $C_1$-field for $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: polynomials, finite-groups, finite-fields, roots

Let $k=\mathbb{F}_q$ Chevalley's theorem states that if $f(x_i)\in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is such that $f(0,...,0)=0$ and $deg(f)<n$, then there is a non-trivial $a_i\in k^n$ such that $f(a_i)=0$.

Is there a version of this over the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $k$? The proof of Chevalley's theorem seems to use that $k$ is at least an integral domain in an essential way.

Comment: A very interesting question. The univariate polynomials that vanish at integer points modulo $p^n$ are well understood, but I don't see a way of modifying the standard argument to take advantage.

Comment: Note: if $n>1$ and $f(x_i)$ contains no terms of degree 1 in addition to the assumption that it contains no terms of degree 0, there is a non-trivial zero for stupid reasons. Namely, choose $a_i=p^{n-1}$ for all $i$. Since each monomial of $f$ is degree at least 2 and $(p^{n-1})^2=0$ in $R$, we have that $f(a_i)=0$.

Comment: Yeah. Also at least one of the linear terms must have a unit coefficient for the same solution not to work. But can't you then make the homogenous linear term a part of a new system of  variables, say $x_1'$=linear term, $x_k'=x_k, k>1$. Then we get a significant reduction: all the terms must contain $x_1'$ for otherwise there is the solution $x_1'=0$, $x_k'=p^{n-1}, k>1$.

Comment: Any chance of Hensel lifting a solution over $\Bbb{F}_p$?